# O substantivo “integral” é masculino ou feminino?

Tags: feminino-masculino

Entrando no [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/integral#Portuguese), vê-se que a palavra *integral* pode ser tanto masculina quanto feminina, e a página da [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Notas) usa-o uma vez como masculino e diz em nota que

> “Em Portugal, a comunidade técnica utiliza *integral* como nome masculino. Por exemplo: o integral de f(x) em [a, b]”.

Porém, todos os dicionários que consultei dizem que *integral* é feminino, inclusive os portugueses [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/integral) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/integral).

Ao mesmo tempo, na Internet, acham-se exemplos de *integral* como masculino com esta [pesquisa](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=integral&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_pt&cr=countryPT&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&tbs=).

Então, o substantivo *integral* é masculino ou feminino? Usá-lo como masculino é informal ou não recomendado, visto que há seu uso, mas não dicionarizado?

Comment: Curioso, sempre a ouvi no masculino!

Answer (score 5):

Nos meus mais de 20 anos nas exatas, passando por diferentes instituições brasileiras, consultando a literatura e interagindo com inúmeras pessoas, jamais vi "integral" sendo usada como substantivo masculino.
E os dicionários que consultei (Houaiss, [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/integral), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/integral), [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/integral) e [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/integral/)) tem todos "integral" apenas como substantivo feminino.

Dito isso, encontram-se muitas instâncias masculinas em pt-PT<sup>1</sup> na web, incluindo os já citados Wiktionary e Wikipédia, e o Jacinto também [comentou](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9119/o-substantvo-integral-%c3%a9-masculino-ou-feminino#comment23368_9119) (corroborado pela [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9124/2764) do bad_coder; e agora também do próprio Jacinto) considerar o masculino normal — o que mostra que, ao menos informalmente e na comunidade técnica em pt-PT, o uso como masculino é prevalente.

Portanto, eu diria que, como o OP sugere, "integral" em geral deve ser usado como feminino quando se dirigindo à comunidade lusófona mais ampla ou pt-BR; mas o masculino é preferível em pt-PT. (Edit: como a resposta do Jacinto agora deixa bem claro.)

---

<sup>1 Também em pt-BR, mas em sua maioria de qualidade duvidosa e/ou escrito por não nativos. Tentei obter medidas mais quantitativas dessa afirmação por meio de buscas no Google, e.g., `"o integral definido" "teorema" site:.pt`, mas as estimativas do número de *hits*<sup>2</sup> são todas estranhamente baixas (já vi o filtro "site" listado como não confiável quando não aplicado a domínios específicos, como aqui: ".br", ".pt").</sup> 
<sup>2 Esse número é apenas uma estimativa que o site provê, que só se torna minimamente confiável ao clicar em "*repeat the search with the omitted results included.*" e ir para a última página (ou ao menos uma muito avançada, quando há um grande número de páginas) de resultados.</sup>

Comment: Usado 100% como masculino em português europeu. Se buscar no Google precedido pelo pronome masculino *"o integral"* ou feminino  *"a integral"* e acrescentar matemática os resultados ficam filtrados por país sem sobreposição.

Comment: @bad_coder Há muitas exceções, mas, sim nota-se claramente a separação. O que não consigo entender é que os dicionários portugueses não reflitam esse uso.

Comment: Tanto no caso do priberam como da infopedia são gralhas, se alguém usar o formulário de contacto eles corrigem. (O conteúdo dos dicionários é orientado por linguístas que para as subtilezas próprias de determinados campos científicos, como a matemática, consultam especialistas dessas áreas. Não sei se o acordo ortográfico terá arbitrado o uso do feminino para integral e foi opção dos editores não mencionar a diferença.)

Answer (score 4):

Ora cá está: o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001) traz ***integral*** como substantivo **masculino** em Portugal e **feminino** no Brasil. No que toca a Portugal, isto corresponde à minha experiência: eu tenho um sólida formação matemática, e nem sabia que *integral* podia ser feminino. Também vem como masculino no dicionário de português-inglês de 1988 da Porto Editora; curiosamente, a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/integral), que é da mesma Porto Editora, dá como feminino.

Agora, o Dicionário da Academia está sozinho neste aspeto. Todos os outros dicionários publicados em Portugal que consultei dizem que o substantivo *integral* é feminino, desde o Domingos Vieira de 1873, passado pelo Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899 e Dicionário da Sociedade de Língua Portuguesa de 1962.

Mas quer-me parecer que o Dicionário da Academia é que tem razão. Eu encontro ***o integral*** em publicações portuguesas desde o século XIX: [*Curso de Mathematicas Puras* de 1839](https://books.google.pt/books?id=swgQseaQd80C&pg=RA1-PA130&dq=%22integral%20definido%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRrcma6fr0AhVz5OAKHe7pD3UQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22integral%20definido%22&f=false) ou este [*O Institudo, Jornal Scientifico e Litterario* de 1855](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WqkDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA105&dq=%22integral%20definido%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRrcma6fr0AhVz5OAKHe7pD3UQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=%22integral%20definido%22&f=false), para indicar só os mais antigos que encontrei. *A integral* só encontrei em publicações brasileiras.

Comment: Jacinto, obrigado pela resposta. O Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa é coisa oficial em Portugal? Se sim, eis a resposta aí!

Comment: @Schilive, não tem nada de oficial; nenhum dicionário tem. Foi simplesmente um dicionário em que um vasta equipa se empenhou. Mas esqueceram-se da palavra *mistura*! Eles simplesmente registaram o uso em Portugal. Não sei qual foi o critério dos outros.

Comment: Jacinto, falei mal. Quis pergunta quanta autoridade tem esse dicionário.

Comment: @Schilive, é um dicionário de referência; dos produzidos em Portugal, o dicionário de referência. Mas parece-me que continuamos a pôr as coisas ao contrário: *integral* é um termo matemático; os matemáticos em Portugal dizem e escrevem *o integral*, pelos visto já há muito tempo, então, no português europeu, é *o integral*, masculino. Não sei é explicar por que os outros dizem que é feminino. Segundo o [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/int%C3%A9grale), o termo foi criado em latim por Bernoulli em 1744; possivelmente ele deu-lhe género feminino; >>

Comment: >> em francês, atestado em 1749, ficou feminino (*intégrale*). Talvez venha daí. Um dicionário de português-inglês que tenho aqui em casa também diz que é masculino; curiosamente é da mesma editora que a Infopédia; acrescentei à resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Na matemática em Portugal *"o integral"* -portanto em português europeu- **∫** é sempre nome próprio masculino.

Pode consultar [o Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=+%22o+integral%22+matem%C3%A1tica) e verificar nos documentos das instituições de ensino portuguesas como é sempre precedido por pronome masculino. Isto é uma tradição antiga sem excepção nos tempos de hoje.

A wikipedia definiu a política de os artigos em português europeu e do brasil serem comuns. Portanto se vermos o artigo [Integral](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) vamos encontrar escrito com 2 géneros *"o integral"* e *"a integral"* o que permite deduzir a variante do português usada pelo autor de cada passagem.

No entanto, em português europeu também é dito *"a integração"* sendo nome feminino formado por derivação e [*"a função integral"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o+integral%22+portugal) em que integral funciona como adjectivo.

---

Isto levanta o problema de encontrarmos as fontes mais antigas possíveis que tratem a/o integral por *"o integral"*. Comecemos por ver que o operador integral como o conhecemos hoje começa com Newton e Leibniz nos finais do séc XVII. Mas se consultarmos as obras publicadas em Portugal deles até ao século XVIII é tudo em latim, francês ou alemão... Do tempo que antecede este periodo da matématica está um bom resumo histórico em [A MATEMÁTICA (1537-1771)](http://www.mat.uc.pt/%7Ejfqueiro/HistUniv.pdf) de João Filipe Queiró.

No período seguinte um dos primeiros livros sobre história da matématica em Portugal é intitulado *"Ensaio historico sobre a origem e progressos das mathematicas em Portugal (Paris, 1819)"* de Francisco Borja de Garção Stockler (está disponível [aqui](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015022369600)) mas não contém a palavra "integral".

Um autor que escreveu sobre a história da matemática sendo frequentmente citado e cujo nome ainda hoje é conhecido foi [Francisco Gomes Teixeira](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Gomes_Teixeira), não consegui encontrar esta obra digitalizada mas pelo título promete:

> [Gomes Teixeira (1851-1933)](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/ciencia/p27.html)
>
> Em 1887, já na Academia Politécnica do Porto, publicou o **Curso de análise infinitesimal, Cálculo Diferencial** (um volume) onde actualizou o ensino da matemática em Portugal. Em 1889 publicou o primeiro volume do **Curso de Análise infinitesimal, Cálculo integral**

Uma pista no final do séc XIX pode ser o dicionário de Cándido de Figueiredo onde está indicado ser "o integral" **"F."** Penso que isto significa "função" e não "feminino" que normalmente é indicado com "f" minúsculo, já "uma differencial" figura como feminino (hoje diria-se "o diferencial" ou "a equação diferencial").

> [Novo dicionário da lÍngua portuguesa](https://books.google.pt/books?id=x1c0mi78WQoC&pg=PT4853)
>
> *Integral*, adj. Inteiro; total. Que intégra. Mathem. Diz-se de um cálculo, que é o inverso do differencial. F. Mathem. Somma dos valores finitos de uma differencial entre os limites dados da variável. (De íntegro)

Comment: Bad_coder, obrigado pela resposta. De curiosidade, como sabes que *o integral* é tradição antiga? Eu não achei nenhum corpus com publicação científica suficiente.

Comment: @Schilive Deixa cá ver, porque conheci matemáticos portugueses que agora teriam mais de 100 anos e sempre os ouvi dizer "o integral" no masculino.

Comment: Bad_coder, obrigado. Interessante. Será que matemáticos brasileiros velhos assim também falavam *a integral*? Ou será isso coisa recente?

Comment: @Schilive boa pergunta... Editei  o post, começo a ter a impressão que em Portugal algures antes the 1900 dizia-se "a integral" e que depois passou a dizer-se "o integral" enquanto no Brasil se mateve o uso do género mais antigo. Documentos digitalizados deste periodo não encontrei.

Comment: @bad_coder Se adiantou a mim: eu ia perguntar justamente sobre essa transição. Ótima adição.

Comment: @stafusa explicar a lógica do campo editorial e dos textos científicos daquele tempo é complicado, a maioria dos matemáticos e físicos que conheço terminam a carreira sem ler os originais de Newton ou Maxwell porque são textos muito abstactos, do estilo filosófico, cheios de "éter" e metáforas. Eu acho que o termo "integral" não terá sido traduzido durante o séc XVIII, depois vieram as invasões napoleônicas, a independência do Brasil, a guerra Miguelista, etc... nesse contexto a publicação científica na Lusofonia teve uma estagnação e crise.

Comment: @stafusa o tipo de pesquisa histórica que é necessária para esclarecer isto a fundo teria de ser feita por consulta a manuscritos do século XVIII porque os textos científicos impressos nas primeiras décadas do cálculo infinitesimal eram em língua estrangeira portanto se no vernacular tratavam "o integral matemático" como masculino ou feminino a prática teria precedido a dicionarística. Textos digitalizados  sobre este assunto desse periodo são escassos, o mais provável seria encontrar a informação mecionada como citação em artigo ou tese contemporâneos.

Comment: @stafusa Mas no fundo a questão remete para a história e evolução das diferenças entre o português científico de Portugal e do Brasil. O que neste caso exige uma dupla pesquisa e comparação histórica, é uma questão fascinante.

Comment: @bad_coder Concordo. Seria preciso encontrar os primeiros textos em português sobre o assunto, o que certamente não poderia ter acontecido antes do século 18, já que o termo [se estabeleceu](https://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html) apenas no finalzinho do 17: "Leibniz in 1696 adopted the term calculus integralis, already suggested by Jacques Bernoulli in 1690".

Comment: No Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899, vem f minúsculo "*adj* [...]; *f* somma dos valores finitos [...]"; este *f* é abreviatura de substantivo feminino. Na edição de 1913 é que vem F, mas não aparece nenhum F maiúsculo na lista de abreviações; penso tratar-se duma gralha. O teu 4º parágrafo não faz grande sentido. Em "a função integral", *integral* é adjetivo, e é de dois géneros; o substantivo é *função*. E os substantivos formados pelo sufixo -*ção* são sempre femininos independentemente do género do radical: *o formato - a formatação; o número - a numeração*.

Comment: @Jacinto Obrigado pela correcção, fiz um erro nesse parágrafo porque escrevi isto meio à pressa para não deixar o Schilive sem resposta. Eu acho que a parte fundamental da prova é o uso generalizado do masculino no Google para os resultados em Portugal. Tentei encontrar fontes documentais mais antigas mas era difícil sem investir um enormidade de tempo na pesquisa, por agora foi o melhor que arranjei.

Comment: Lol, eu sei o tempo que demora pesquisar o Google Books! O *Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* (Porto, 1873) de Domingos Vieira (de cuja cópia física eu sou orgulhoso proprietário) também diz que é feminino. Eu estudei e trabalho no ISEG, por onde passaram grandes matemáticos portugueses (Bento de Jesus Caraça, Bento Murteira) e só ouvi e li *o integral*. Parece claramente haver aqui em Portugal um divórcio entre lexicógrafos e matemáticos. Há uma coisa parecida na Medicina: os dicionários trazem *glicemia*, mas eu ouço os médicos pronunciarem sempre como se fosse *glicémia*.